# With the unfortunate death of every human living less than 1000ft above sea level, who would be left?

Tags: science-based, humans, earth, post-apocalypse, modern-age

Obviously the short answer is 'everyone living 1001+ feet above sea level', but I'm looking for something a bit more nuanced.

Imagine a rolling wave of death - a 'turning off' of the brain, no other trauma involved - originating from France, moving at about the speed of sound. It affects only humans, and once the wave has made its way across the entire world it stops (no ripples, 'aftershocks' or repetitions). The wave is visible only as a slight disturbance in the air as it moves.

Who would be left to pick up the pieces? Which countries/communities/groups would be high enough above sea level, or would be able to *get* high enough before the wave hit them? Which of these groups would probably die off shortly after through lack of trade/resources/contact, and which might flourish?

But in essence, and most importantly, who would be left?

Comment: Related: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34626/will-humanity-survive-if-only-larger-cities-are-left/34636#34636

Comment: This could be answered by looking at an elevation map. Regardless, there are several questions here, some of which would require an answer to be unacceptably long (or a bare list). Trying to describe the immediate and long-term consequences of hundreds or thousands of places around the world is far too much for one post.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is hard... The main reason is no one has collated the data really, but from [this paper](http://lab.rockefeller.edu/cohenje/PDFs/266CohenSmallPNASHypsoDemo.pdf) I can give you a rough estimate of 150 to 300 million at base...

But then there is a second problem with your question. We have worldwide 24/7 new coverage and people would likely pick up on what's going on. Europe would be decimated, but the Americas, Asia, Africa, and Australia all have at least 4 hours before they were hit and they have a high chance of figuring out getting a theory out there and people live near area that are higher all over that are fairly close by so there is a strong chance that the rest of the world survives with 5 to 6 billion people... It just depends on the individuals willingness to listen, believe, act, and how quickly people figure it out and when it happens. If it happens in the early afternoon in France it would be a lot more devistating than if it happened in the late afternoon or evening because people in the other countries for the US but vice verca for Asia.

Comment: Well, airtravel tickets will sell at a premium (if Delta can handle it).

Comment: How can it be reported on coverage if one would be dead before they can report it?

Comment: I doubt people in Europe would work out what had happened fast enough to warn Asia/Africa/America/Australia, the event is too specific and unusual.

Comment: But if they did, I'm driving. I don't have to get far and I know to avoid the freeway.

Answer (score 1):

A rolling wave of death that travels over all media, land and water is fairly difficult to conceive, especially if it does not propagate vertically as well as horizontally. If it travels at the speed of sound, would sound proof/ airtight, rooms/bunkers/vehicles be unaffected or at least weaken the effects? Short term coma or just getting knocked out, instead of dead?

At the speed of sound at sea level, it'll take about 16 hours to cover the globe. Assuming that death is instantaneous, there will be nobody left to raise the alarm, i.e., by the time you notice what's going on, you're already dead. The only warning people will get is that telecommunications become unresponsive, since there's nobody on the other end.

The survivors will be the inhabitants of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_buildings_with_100_floors_or_more; and people currently on aircraft above 1000ft and people living in the Alps, the Andes (central S. America, in general), some of central America, the Himalayan foothills, some parts of China, and in the Ural mountains, off the top of my head.

Most of these people will die within the week, as corpses begin to fester and breed disease. If the wave affects animals as well, then most mammals, at least, probably also fish and reptiles, will die as well, adding to the mess. The knock on effects on the environment will kill most of them anyway, as the wind and rain washes the rotten bodies downstream.

People dependent on modern infrastructure will be severely affected, as there will be nobody left to maintain them; those communities that still aren't so dependent will carry business on as usual, for the moment.

By rule of thumb, 1 kg of biomass gives 1 mol of methane. Let's say 6 billion dead, 70 kg on average, gives 10^13 litres of methane at room temperature/1atm. Global warming effects aside, methane is slightly heavier than air, so will not easily dispersed in enclosed spaces, like cities, which is where most bodies will be. Cities, therefore, will be a fire hazard until sparks from unattended fires, electrical equipment etc., burn them down. Hopefully, this will deal with most of the the water pollution and disease issues.
Nuclear power plants, chemical factories,etc., are the next source of concern, along with nuclear and chemical arsenals. Depending on how the safeties are set up, unattended, these systems will force an automatic shut down. Otherwise, with no load to supply, the plants will explode; the nuclear arsenals will assume a decapitating strike and launch at preassigned targets, at best irradiate everything within their blast radius, at worst rupture the Earth's core.

In any case, the sensible thing for the isolated survivors to do would be to stay where they are, for the next few decades or so; afterwards, it depends on the survivors' technical expertise and what's left.

Comment: Much more territory than you realize is above 1000 feet...see the map I linked to.

Comment: wouldn't be surprised. As I said, off the top of my head

Comment: Warning would spread--there are tons of webcams--people would see it.  There would also be planes that landed behind the wave and saw the results.

Comment: 32 hours is wrong. If you start at a point and go one direction it'd take 32 hours, but it's going all directions at once which would mean 16 hours to cover the whole globe. France is about 5 or 6 hours from the East coast of the US and Hong Kong. If you want to see how far it'd go in x time it's fairly easy to see it with most art programs with the circle tool...

Comment: true. Corrected above

Comment: @LorenPechtel: What's more likely, "OMG! Everybody's dropping dead!" or, "Seriously not funny, guys! Call me back."  Planes can't land because the control tower people and ground crew are dead. News will spread, but to late to make any difference.

Comment: @nzaman Some planes will land anyway because of fuel.  They'll come in and not get the tower and eventually divert--but the divert airport is likely also low.  They'll burn through their reserve and have to land.  While they certainly **could** reach an airport that's still in operation they won't know what's going on and thus won't head for higher altitude airports.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Only in smaller airports; in larger airports, there'd be hundreds of aircraft circling at a time. Without a tower coordinating them, many will break away for fear of collisions. If some were on a landing approach, or otherwise under 1,000ft when the wave hits, other flights could see crashes that block the runway or other infrastructure, which would provide a reasonable explanation for why the tower cut off, e.g., the transmitters lost power; emergency crews evacuated the tower; they're scrambling to control the ground situation; terrorist attack, etc. No point sticking around

Comment: ...continued: While they will all get desperate enough to land eventually, by the time they sort out matters amongst themselves, in absence of tower instructions, then land, they'll be cautious and explore slowly, especially when they find the first bodies. By the time they get around to warning someone capable of receiving their message, it will probably be far too late for them to respond. Consider: Paris Airport, 16 hrs left before the wave covers the globe. Runways clear. ~45 mins trying to raise the tower, ~30 mins sorting out landing queue, ~1 hr for 1st few planes to land,

Comment: contd. ~1 hr to form teams to explore while keeping the passengers calm; 1st body found a few minutes in; warn crew on plane to try to raise an alarm by radio, alert other planes: 30 min delay; explore even more slowly, additional teams heading to tower and exits ~1hr; dead bodies everywhere, nearest radios/emergency services not responding, what's going on~1hr; get someone up on a small plane, while trying international receivers~2 hrs; news is out, low flyby reports Paris is dead. 8hrs gone, you've reached Russia and the US, so has the wave.

Comment: By the time people are going, "What? All Europe is dead!", your recipients are cutting off. The southern hemisphere, China, Japan, etc., receive the message, "People are dying, how and why we don't know". Those who haven't died, through being too high are hysterical, cue more time wasted. Rioting and looting breaks out. Rather than figure out what's going on and why, the administration is too busy trying to control  violent mobs. ... No, they're not going to get the message in time to do anything useful.

Comment: You're not showing that the word wouldn't get out.  Whether it would be put together into an understanding of the threat in time to do anything about it is another matter, though.

Comment: I said, `...there will be nobody left to raise the alarm, i.e., by the time you notice what's going on, you're already dead. The only warning people will get is that telecommunications become unresponsive, since there's nobody on the other end.` I never said word wouldn't get out, but that an alarm wouldn't be raised till it was too late. I've stated as much in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

[This tool](http://www.floodmap.net/) lets you set a water height and see what areas would flood.  It's a good gauge of what areas of the world would survive.

A surprisingly large percentage of the world's land is over 1000 feet elevation.  However, nearly all of the major population centers are coastal, so most of the world population would die (Note how well the red areas of [this population density map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_density#/media/File:World_population_density_1994_-_with_equator.png) correlate with the areas that are flooded in the above map).

Most of the major areas of economic activity would be completely obliterated.  Most world governments would be wiped out, and chaos would ensue.  Some key industries, like fishing and shipping, would be completely gone, with major effects on the surviving population.